# Javascript for the jsp

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, servlets

how to add javascript to the below code such that i can refresh it to obtain any entries without refreshing the whole page

```
<label for="textarea">
  <blockquote>
    <ul>
      <ul>
        <li><strong>Session Progress</strong></li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </blockquote>
</label>
<p>
  <textarea name="textarea" cols="88" rows="33" id="textarea"></textarea>
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Front end

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {   
    $('#button').click(function() {
      $.get('/backEnd', function(data) {
        $("#textarea").html(data);
      });
    });
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<textarea name="textarea" cols="88" rows="33" id="textarea"></textarea>
<button id="button">Update</button>
</body>

</html>
```

## Back end

```
@WebServlet(name = "updaterServlet", urlPatterns = { "/backEnd" })
public class UpdaterServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;UTF-8");

        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.write(new java.util.Date().toString());
        writer.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
         doGet(request, response);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery and make an Ajax call.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Seems that's what you need.

An Ajax call calls your server, pulls some data,
then when the response is received, you select
some elements on your page and update them.
For that second part you can also use jQuery.

If you don't want to use jQuery but plain JavaScript,
you can still make an Ajax call but it's more difficult
and error prone.

See also: [Wikipedia - Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)